# Converting UTF characters to Unicode in iOS

Tags: objective-c, unicode, utf, cjk

My MySQL server collation is utf8_general_ci. In my DB I have stored an entry for the city 横浜. Saves, renders and searches via the api fine without any headache.

I'm now trying to sync up my iOS app to my API. I can successfully search for the word, but after clicking on it, and trying to render the Unicode back on the iOS app, I keep falling short. My JSON returns the following in the log \U00e6\U00a8\U00aa\U00e6\U00b5\U009c\U00e3\U0080\U0080, but it keeps rendering as æ¨ªæµã. I've tried the following with no success:

`[[item valueForKey:@"name"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U00" withString:@"x"]`

How can I get it to render as 横浜?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're managing to treat each individual code unit of each utf-8 encoded code point in a string as a separate code point of its own. Usual suspects are things that iterate over a `char *` C style string a char at a time. Would have to see all the relevant code to help narrow it down more.

Comment: Yuck.  That a weird variant on Mojibake.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the connection parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *correct = [NSString stringWithCString:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

using this one should be able to convert to 横浜